# how to pause DontDestroyOnLoad audio in UNITY?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this code to to play audio throughout all scene its working properly and the pause is working too. but when I leave the scene and go back the audio wont pause anymore. what should I do to pause the audio?

```c#
public AudioClip sound;

public AudioSource source 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return GetComponent<AudioSource>(); 
    }
}

void Start ()
{
    gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>(); 

    source.clip = sound;

    if (source.playOnAwake == true)
        source.Play ();    

    Button butn = GameObject.Find ("soundButton").GetComponent<Button>();

    butn.onClick.AddListener(PlaySoud);     
}

public void PlaySoud ()
{
    if (source.isPlaying)
    {
        source.Pause();
    }
    else
    {
        source.Play ();         
    }
}

void Awake()
{
    GameObject[] obj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("soundobject");

    if(obj.Length > 1)
    {
        Destroy (this.gameObject);
    }

    DontDestroyOnLoad (this.gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You may find [OnLevelWasLoaded](https://docs.unity3d.com/455/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnLevelWasLoaded.html) handy.
2. You do this:

   ```c#
   public AudioSource source 
   { 
       get 
       { 
           return GetComponent<AudioSource>();
       } 
   }
   ```

   But I think a private variable would be better.
3. ```c#
   gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();`
   ```

   why not add this component in the editor?
4. I mentioned (1.) because `Start()` and `Awake()` are called only when you instantiate / create objects. Also on scene load.

   So your `dontDestroyOnLoad` object will not execute `Start()` and `Awake()` again on the still existing object. (just to clarify this)
5. If you load another scene containing an audio-object, the `Awake()` is called once. On the newly loaded. Okay until here.

   The awake will then delete the "old" one because both have tag `soundobject` (**double check that this is the case in all scenes!**) - but **afterwards** you call `DontDestroyOnLoad` on the (probably) destroyed object. see [answers.unity post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/233284/objects-being-duplicated-with-dontdestroyonload.html) - there is a snippet where they call `DontDestroyOnLoad` first. It's very similar to yours.
6. You could try to call `source.Pause()` before you destroy - this might hint you to your problem.
7. use

   ```c#
   Debug.Log("I am " + this.gameobject.name + " and I will be destroyed,  my audio is " + (source.isPlaying() ? "playing." : "not playing."));
   ```

   before the destroy call. Then check the hierarchie and the console to see what was kept and what was deleted.

Report back if this doesn't solve the problem.